# Filtering out objects in an array of objects without any null values

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm trying to filter out api output _that doesn't include **any** null values - the api output (JSON) looks like so:

```
[{ title:
        'Bayern Munich defenders are scared of damned talented Jadon Sancho, says Borussia Dortmund team-mate Axel Witsel - Goal',
    date: '2019-08-04T11:42:00Z',
    image: null,
    description:
        'As Leeds kick off the new season with hopes of returning to the Premier League, we remember their painful demise from 15 years ago',
    link:
        'https://www.goal.com/en/news/even-bayern-defenders-are-scared-of-damned-talented-sancho/huf85pn3ob4s1r0fcjq52nsqe' },
    { title:
        'Manchester City y Liverpool se enfrentan con la Community Shield en juego: hora y TV - infobae',
    date: '2019-08-04T11:36:59Z',
    image:
        'https://www.infobae.com/new-resizer/ZvS6Vs3f7Qa_11HIibSiMy8DOUw=/1200x0/filters:quality(100)/s3.amazonaws.com/arc-wordpress-client-uploads/infobae-wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/04082112/Guardiola-Klopp.jpg',
    description:
        'El campeón y el subcampeón de la Premier League se enfrentan con el primer título de la temporada en juego. En la previa, hubo un duelo verbal entre Pep Guardiola y Jürgen Klopp. A las 11, por ESPN2',
    link:
        'https://www.infobae.com/america/deportes/futbol-europeo/2019/08/04/manchester-city-vs-liverpool-community-shield-2019/' },
    { title:
        'Ireland\'s Hourihane bangs in two stunning free-kicks ahead of Villa\'s Premier League return - The42',
    date: '2019-08-04T11:33:00Z',
    image:
        'https://img2.thejournal.ie/article/4752619/river/?height=400&version=4752623',
    description: null,
    link:
        'https://www.the42.ie/conor-hourihane-free-kicks-leipzig-4752619-Aug2019/' } ]
```

The code I currently has achieves this, but it's so bulky and uses **a lot** of conditionals - which I'd like to avoid. Can something like this be achieved?

```
let filteredArr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i].title !== null &&
        data[i].date !== null &&
        data[i].image !== null &&
        data[i].description !== null &&
        data[i].link !== null) {
        filteredArr.push(data[i])
    }
}
```

The output would be like so:

```
   [{ title:
        'Manchester City y Liverpool se enfrentan con la Community Shield en juego: hora y TV - infobae',
    date: '2019-08-04T11:36:59Z',
    image:
        'https://www.infobae.com/new-resizer/ZvS6Vs3f7Qa_11HIibSiMy8DOUw=/1200x0/filters:quality(100)/s3.amazonaws.com/arc-wordpress-client-uploads/infobae-wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/04082112/Guardiola-Klopp.jpg',
    description:
        'El campeón y el subcampeón de la Premier League se enfrentan con el primer título de la temporada en juego. En la previa, hubo un duelo verbal entre Pep Guardiola y Jürgen Klopp. A las 11, por ESPN2',
    link:
        'https://www.infobae.com/america/deportes/futbol-europeo/2019/08/04/manchester-city-vs-liverpool-community-shield-2019/' } ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the array by checking all values.

```js
var data = [{ title: 'Bayern Munich defenders are scared of damned talented Jadon Sancho, says Borussia Dortmund team-mate Axel Witsel - Goal', date: '2019-08-04T11:42:00Z', image: null, description: 'As Leeds kick off the new season with hopes of returning to the Premier League, we remember their painful demise from 15 years ago', link: 'https://www.goal.com/en/news/even-bayern-defenders-are-scared-of-damned-talented-sancho/huf85pn3ob4s1r0fcjq52nsqe' }, { title: 'Manchester City y Liverpool se enfrentan con la Community Shield en juego: hora y TV - infobae', date: '2019-08-04T11:36:59Z', image: 'https://www.infobae.com/new-resizer/ZvS6Vs3f7Qa_11HIibSiMy8DOUw=/1200x0/filters:quality(100)/s3.amazonaws.com/arc-wordpress-client-uploads/infobae-wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/04082112/Guardiola-Klopp.jpg', description: 'El campeón y el subcampeón de la Premier League se enfrentan con el primer título de la temporada en juego. En la previa, hubo un duelo verbal entre Pep Guardiola y Jürgen Klopp. A las 11, por ESPN2', link: 'https://www.infobae.com/america/deportes/futbol-europeo/2019/08/04/manchester-city-vs-liverpool-community-shield-2019/' }, { title: 'Ireland\'s Hourihane bangs in two stunning free-kicks ahead of Villa\'s Premier League return - The42', date: '2019-08-04T11:33:00Z', image: 'https://img2.thejournal.ie/article/4752619/river/?height=400&version=4752623', description: null, link: 'https://www.the42.ie/conor-hourihane-free-kicks-leipzig-4752619-Aug2019/' }],
    result = data.filter(o => Object.values(o).every(v => v !== null));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter function. The **items** variable contains your original data.

```
const filtered = items.filter(function(item) {
  for (var key in item) {
    if (null == item[key])
      return false;
  }
  return true;
});
```